# this element with jquery problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have this javascript code:

```
// Meldingen groen / oranje / rood
$("#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li").hide();

$("#blokken .overzicht .matrix td.radio.groen :radio").change(function(){
 $("#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li").hide();

 $(this).parents("#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li.groen").fadeIn(600);
});

$("#blokken .overzicht .matrix td.radio.oranje").click(function(){
 $("#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li").hide();
 $("#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li.oranje").fadeIn(600);

});

$("#blokken .overzicht .matrix td.radio.rood").click(function(){
 $("#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li").hide();
 $("#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li.rood").fadeIn(600);

});
```

On my HTML document I have a number of radio buttons. When the user clicks on a radio button I want to show a particular `<li>`, i.e. if the user clicks on the `.groen` radio button then `li.groen` will be shown, etc. But when I click on a radio button right now all of the `<li>` elements under `ul.melding` are shown. What's wrong?

Comment: It would help to see the markup too I think.

Comment: Please correct[grammatical]  your question,  It's not understandable. May be an Online example explains more about your problem..

Comment: Yes, HTML source is definitely needed. Maybe you could even simplify your problem by pruning your jQuery selectors, dropping those multi-level selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should *really* do is set up a single delegated event handler for *all* the radio buttons, and then find the corresponding "li" from the radio button class.

```
$("#blokken").delegate('.overzicht .matrix td.radio input:radio', 'click', function() {
  $('#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li').hide();

  var checked = $('#blokken .overzicht .matrix td.radio input:radio:checked'),
    $td =  checked.parent('td.radio');
  $('#blokken .overzicht ul.melding li.' + $td.attr('class')).fadeIn(600);
});
```

Now, if the `<td>` elements have more complicated "class" values, then you'd have to pluck out the color some other way.

(*edit* I fixed this up a little - the code triggers on "click" and then re-discovers the current checked radio button. Radio buttons can be problematic in IE because "change" doesn't fire until the control loses focus.)

(more edits - I need more coffee today I think :-)